# How to loop on groups in photoshop?

Tags: javascript, photoshop

I have this code and it works, but it does not see the text inside the layer group and does not iterate over it.

```
var itemsAry=['emil','lardtub','100','jsbus', 'rasmus','null','1000000'];

var layers = app.activeDocument.layers;  
for (var i =0; i<layers.length; i++) {  

    if (layers[i].kind == "LayerKind.TEXT") {
        
        layers[i].textItem.contents=itemsAry[i]
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you give more inputs on **app.activeDoument.layers**?

Comment: this is a call to layers
and this is a call to group with layers
``app.activeDocument.layerSets``

Comment: Have you tried to search the stackoverflow? There's at least a dozen of posts with the full layerstack iteration scripts both with DOM and AM approaches

Comment: @SergeyKritskiy it's true, it's there. But if you don't know what to look for - it's not that obvious. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whilst [looping through all layers in a document is on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26623283/photoshop-javascript-to-get-all-layers-in-the-active-document), it can be confusing from looping over a number of layers to the awkwardness of looping over a psd with groups in it.

Basically, you need a recursive function to loop over the groups.

Point of note, make sure to switch off any dialog boxes at the start of the script when changing text. Otherwise you have to validate every text change confirmation.

```
// Switch off any dialog boxes
displayDialogs = DialogModes.NO; // OFF

var itemsAry=['emil','lardtub','100','jsbus', 'rasmus','null','1000000'];


// group layer vegetables
var theLayers = collectAllLayers(app.activeDocument, 0);


// function collect all layers
function collectAllLayers (theParent, level)
{
   for (var m = theParent.layers.length - 1; m >= 0; m--)
   {
      var theLayer = theParent.layers[m];
      
      // apply the function to layersets;
      if (theLayer.typename == "ArtLayer")
      {
            if (theLayer.kind == "LayerKind.TEXT") 
            {
            
                theLayer.textItem.contents=itemsAry[m];
            }
      }
      else
      {
         collectAllLayers(theLayer, level + 1)
      }
   }
}

// Make sure dialogs back on
displayDialogs = DialogModes.ALL; // ON
```